# VBA code hanging Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code to grab the raw data in a file and summarize the data based to "date" of report and copy this summarized data into the target workbook according to the "date" value.

When I tried to run this code. it works fine for one file, but hangs up in another file. When I try to debug it I am not able to follow the flow of code.  It breaks up suddenly. Can you help me in fixing this issue?

```
Option Explicit
Sub file_select()
Dim RequiredFileName As Variant, i As Integer
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
' making weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
'RequiredFileName = "c:\myfiles\test.xls"
On Error GoTo EndNow
RequiredFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="ALL Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Get File", MultiSelect:=True)
For i = 1 To UBound(RequiredFileName)
    MsgBox RequiredFileName(i), , GetFileName(CStr(RequiredFileName(i)))
Next i
For i = 1 To UBound(RequiredFileName)
    Call ProcessOpenFile(RequiredFileName(i), targetWorkbook)
Next i
EndNow: End Sub

Function GetFileName(filespec As String)
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
GetFileName = fso.GetFileName(filespec)
End Function

Sub ProcessOpenFile(RequiredFileName, targetWorkbook As Workbook)
Dim RequiredWorkbook As Workbook
'Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
' get the required workbook
Set RequiredWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(RequiredFileName)

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary_NV")
Dim RequiredSheet As Worksheet
Set RequiredSheet = RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1)        'here assumed that source workbook consists only of one sheet i.e., is the required sheet.
RequiredWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "SUMMARY" & Sheets.Count
Call Sort_Before(RequiredWorkbook)        'sorting the required file data according to date.

If RequiredSheet.Name = "EVDO_SC_Summary" Then
    Call ProcessEVDO(RequiredSheet)        'get the summary of report
    Call Sort_After(RequiredWorkbook)        ' sort the summary according to date
    Call DateChange(RequiredWorkbook)        'changing date format
ElseIf RequiredSheet.Name = "CDMAVoice_SC_Summary" Then
    Call ProcessVoice(RequiredSheet)
    Call Sort_After(RequiredWorkbook)
    Call DateChange(RequiredWorkbook)
ElseIf RequiredSheet.Name = "CDMAData_SC_Summary" Then
    Call ProcessData(RequiredSheet)
    Call Sort_After(RequiredWorkbook)
    Call DateChange(RequiredWorkbook)
End If

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim LastRow_Req As Integer
Dim LastRow_Tar As Integer
Dim LastCol_Req As Integer
LastRow_Req = RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row        'last row summary data
LastCol_Req = RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column        'last column of summary data
LastRow_Tar = targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row        'last row of target sheet used
RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B1").Resize(LastRow_Req, LastCol_Req - 1).Select        'selecting summary data for copying
Selection.Copy

If targetSheet.Cells(LastRow_Tar, 1).Value < RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Value Then        'if date entered in target sheet last cell is less
    If RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "EVDO_SC_Summary" Then        'then the summary report date
        targetSheet.Activate
        Cells(LastRow_Tar + 1, 16).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                      :=False, Transpose:=False
        Cells(LastRow_Tar + 1, 1).Select
        Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, LastRow_Tar + 1, 1)
    ElseIf RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "CDMAVoice_SC_Summary" Then
        targetSheet.Activate
        Cells(LastRow_Tar + 1, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                      :=False, Transpose:=False
        Cells(LastRow_Tar + 1, 1).Select
        Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, LastRow_Tar + 1, 1)
    ElseIf RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "CDMAData_SC_Summary" Then
        targetSheet.Activate
        Cells(LastRow_Tar + 1, 9).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                      :=False, Transpose:=False
        Cells(LastRow_Tar + 1, 1).Select
        Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, LastRow_Tar + 1, 1)
    End If
End If

For iRow = targetSheet.Range("A12").Row To LastRow_Tar
    RequiredWorkbook.Activate
    If targetSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value < RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Value Then
        GoTo A
    ElseIf targetSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Value Then
        If RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "EVDO_SC_Summary" Then
            targetSheet.Activate
            Cells(iRow, 16).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                          :=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells(iRow, 1).Select
            Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, iRow, 1)
            Exit For
        ElseIf RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "CDMAVoice_SC_Summary" Then
            targetSheet.Activate
            Cells(iRow, 2).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                          :=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells(iRow, 1).Select
            Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, iRow, 1)
            Exit For
        ElseIf RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "CDMAData_SC_Summary" Then
            targetSheet.Activate
            Cells(iRow, 9).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                          :=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells(iRow, 1).Select
            Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, iRow, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    ElseIf targetSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value > RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1").Value Then
        If RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "EVDO_SC_Summary" Then
            targetSheet.Activate
            Cells(iRow, 16).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Exit For
            Cells(iRow, 1).Select
            Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, iRow, 1)
        ElseIf RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "CDMAVoice_SC_Summary" Then
            targetSheet.Activate
            Cells(iRow, 2).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Cells(iRow, 1).Select
            Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, iRow, 1)
            Exit For
        ElseIf RequiredWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "CDMAData_SC_Summary" Then
            targetSheet.Activate
            Cells(iRow, 9).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Cells(iRow, 1).Select
            Call Date_update(RequiredWorkbook, targetWorkbook, iRow, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
A:     Next
RequiredWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend getting rid of the on error statements.... at least then you will get an error message.

Comment: I do see a lot of opportunity to refactor that code into something more readable, but it's impossible to tell what your problem might be without any error message or even a rough idea of which actual part of your code is responsible.

Comment: I got rid off error statements and try to run, it is working fine for one file but in other files it is just running and using lot of CPU memory and not giving out any error msg.

Comment: Have u tried to put some messageboxes to your code, so u can limit the place where the problem could be?

Comment: Thanks For all the help guys found the problem.. Code is going into infinite loop... is there any error msg available in VBA for infinite loop !?!

Comment: Hi, usually when I suspect a infinite loop or when the vba program hands, I will try Ctrl + Break to BREAK the code from executing then you have an idea when it hands.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in a comment "Code is going into infinite loop" –  [user1806794](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806794/user1806794)